# Посчитать количество блоков в которых есть класс

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как посчитать количество блоков puzzle_block в которых есть хотя бы один класс notValid и где все блоки с классом valid?

```js
$(function() {

$('#check').click(function(){

var badAnswers = jQuery('.notValid').length;
var goodAnswers = jQuery('.valid').length;
$('.count_answers').html('Правильных ответов '+goodAnswers+', неправильных ответов '+badAnswers+'');      

});

});
```

```css
li {
display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000; padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="puzzle">

<div class="count_answers"></div>

<div class="puzzle_block jMyPuzzle">
  <p id="trials"></p>
  <ul class="puzzels"><li class="valid">1</li> <li class="valid">2</li> <li class="valid">3</li> <li class="valid">4</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="puzzle_block jMyPuzzle2">
  <p id="trials"></p>
  <ul class="puzzels"><li class="notValid">4</li> <li class="valid">2</li> <li class="valid">3</li> <li class="notValid">1</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="puzzle_block jMyPuzzle3">
  <p id="trials"></p>
  <ul class="puzzels"><li class="valid">1</li> <li class="valid">2</li> <li class="valid">3</li> <li class="valid">4</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="puzzle_block jMyPuzzle3">
  <p id="trials"></p>
  <ul class="puzzels"><li class="notValid">2</li> <li class="notValid">1</li> <li class="valid">3</li> <li class="valid">4</li></ul>
</div>

<button id="check">Check</button>


</div>
```

Comment: `console.log($('.valid').closest('.notValid').length)`? Я вопрос не понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проходим по циклу `$('.puzzle_block').each` и в нем с помощью метода `.find()` ищем элементы с определенным классом, если есть то добавляем `+1` в переменную счетчик.

```js
$(function() {

$('#check').click(function(){

var badAnswers = jQuery('.notValid').length;
var goodAnswers = jQuery('.valid').length;
$('.count_answers').html('Правильных ответов '+goodAnswers+', неправильных ответов '+badAnswers+'');      

});
//Начало кода считывания
var val_count = 0;
var noval_count = 0;
$('.puzzle_block').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('.valid').length > 0){
    val_count++;
  }
  if($(this).find('.notValid').length > 0){
    noval_count++;
  }
});

console.log(val_count);
console.log(noval_count);

//Конец кода считывания

});
```

```css
li {
display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000; padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="puzzle">

<div class="count_answers"></div>

<div class="puzzle_block jMyPuzzle">
  <p id="trials"></p>
  <ul class="puzzels"><li class="valid">1</li> <li class="valid">2</li> <li class="valid">3</li> <li class="valid">4</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="puzzle_block jMyPuzzle2">
  <p id="trials"></p>
  <ul class="puzzels"><li class="notValid">4</li> <li class="valid">2</li> <li class="valid">3</li> <li class="notValid">1</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="puzzle_block jMyPuzzle3">
  <p id="trials"></p>
  <ul class="puzzels"><li class="valid">1</li> <li class="valid">2</li> <li class="valid">3</li> <li class="valid">4</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="puzzle_block jMyPuzzle3">
  <p id="trials"></p>
  <ul class="puzzels"><li class="notValid">2</li> <li class="notValid">1</li> <li class="valid">3</li> <li class="valid">4</li></ul>
</div>

<button id="check">Check</button>


</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли! :)